# Change button text over other button android

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I create an application in android studio and I need advice, I got one button, and I need to change the text on the second button clicks through to the first. I have a code that changes only TextView but not the text on the button.

```
 NewText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
 ChangeText = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ch_txt_ger);

 final TextView finalNewText1 = NewText;
 ChangeText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //Set Text on button click via this function.

        finalNewText1.setText(" (Frohe Weihnachten) ");

    }
 });
```

Comment: `ChangeText.setText(...)` ?

Comment: I'm just going to comment that there's no need to have a 2nd reference to the same TextView (`R.id.textView1`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same concept as you did for textView

```
Button SecondButton,ChangeText; // declaring the buttons
SecondButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
ChangeText = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ch_txt_ger);

ChangeText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //This changes the text on the second button

        SecondButton.setText("New Text Here");

    }
 });

SecondButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //Do anything

    }
 });
```

Comment: Can you please expand a little more detail? Beginner here and somehow it does not work

Answer (score 0):

```
      Button ChangeText;
    ChangeText = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ch_txt_ger);
    ChangeText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //part to change the button text
            Button tmp_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ch_txt_ger);
            tmp_button.setText("Frohe Weihnachten");

            //part to change the textview text
            TextView NewText
            NewText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            finalNewText1.setText(" (Frohe Weihnachten) ");

        }
    });
```

[After Clicking outlooking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhPxK.png)

Here you go: You can define a temporary button variable and make the change on it if setting the same button on its own clicking is causing problems.
And if the text will not change according to user, and if you know it like On/OFF, Red/Green you can also code it with a *selector* file which would make the java code look more clean.

A tiny advise: Defining the TextViews and Buttons that will get affected should all be written in the same function and close to the place where they are being changed for you to keep track of where you coded them.

Answer (score 0):

I would add one thing, in case if you want to save the new button name when you close and reopen your app, you could use Shared Preferences: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html